# PWA for website based on html not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to integrate PWA into this html page https://moodmap.app/ .

I have used a manifest and created the service worker required - but it won't load for some reason?

directory layout below.

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   ├── icons.svg
    │   ├── images
    │   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
    │   │   ├── favicon.png
    │   │   ├── image01.jpg
    │   │   ├── image02.jpg
    │   │   ├── _image02.svg
    │   │   └── share.jpg
    │   ├── LovelyChart.custom.js
    │   ├── main.css
    │   ├── main.js
    │   ├── main_large.css
    │   ├── main.min.js
    │   ├── noscript.css
    │   ├── noscript_other.css
    │   └── videos
    │       ├── video01.mp4
    │       └── video01.mp4.jpg
    ├── example.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── manifest.json
    ├── pay.html
    ├── serviceworker.js
    ├── signup.html
    └── stats.html
```

servicework.js

```
const staticMoodmap = "dev-MoodMap-site-v1"
const assets = [
  "/",
  "/index.html",
  "/stats.html",
  // "/signup.html",
  // "/pay.html",
  // "/assets/noscript.css",
  // "/assets/main.css",
  "/assets/main.min.js",
  "/assets/LovelyChart.custom.js",
  "/assets/icons.svg",
  "/assets/images/image01.jpg",
  "/assets/images/image02.jpg",
  "/assets/images/share.jpg",
  "/assets/images/_image02.svg",
  "/assets/images/favicon.png",
  "/assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png",
  "/assets/videos/video01.mp4.jpg",
  "/assets/images/video01.mp4",
]

self.addEventListener("install", installEvent => {
  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticMoodmap).then(cache => {
      cache.addAll(assets)
    })
  )
})

self.addEventListener("fetch", fetchEvent => {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(
      caches.match(fetchEvent.request).then(res => {
        return res || fetch(fetchEvent.request)
      })
    )
  })
```

manifest.json

```
 {
        "name": "MoodMap",
        "short_name": "MoodMap",
        "start_url": "./index.html",
        "display": "standalone",
        "background_color": "#fdfdfd",
        "theme_color": "#db4938",
        "orientation": "portrait-primary",
        "icons": [
          {
            "src": "/assets/images/image01.jpg",
            "type": "image/jpg", "sizes": "72x72"
          }
        ]
      }



main.js
```

....

```
 if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker
            .register("./serviceworker.js")
            .then(res => console.log("service worker registered"))
            .catch(err => console.log("service worker not registered", err))
        })
      }
```

So I'm thinking that it has something to do with how I am integrating the javascript? or the directory structure?

Comment: Try out this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-pwa-from-scratch-with-html-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is on setting index.html because this link is not available
https://moodmap.app/index.html

So maybe you should change

```
 "start_url": "./index.html"
```

You should change it to

```
 "start_url": "/index.html"
```

Or

```
"start_url": "/"
```